# Xcode 5 Unsupported Configuration: maximum size is smaller than its content rectangle size

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I am getting 2 warnings with a Table View on my mac osx application. They are both "Unsupported Configuration: maximum size is smaller than its content rectangle size (May result in unexpected runtime behavior)." I have tried "reset to suggested constraints" in the editor, but that doesn't do anything. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I know of that has a “maximum size” is NSWindow. Did you look at the geometry inspector for the window in the XIB file?